# How to test a AS3 Project on Performance?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash

I have done a project in AS3 with the Flash-Builder, and now I want to test my SWF File about the performance. I think it could work when opening it in a browser, but I am not sure how? Thanks!

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255132/profiling-actionscript-3-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Adobe Scout :  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashruntimes/articles/adobe-scout-getting-started.edu.html

Check the below link from Grant Skinner
http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2009/04/as3_performance.html

There is a community managed page as well for speed tests. You might want to look at those as well http://osflash.org/as3_speed_optimizations